# How to configure Merchant account for Kiosk application

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, kiosk-mode

We have a requirement of KIOSK application on windows platform. Each kiosk should have the option to configure the own merchant account (credit card details) at the time of software set up.  As of now we are not using any web api or admin web section, since the version is just a prototype.
 How do we manage “Merchant account” configuration?
At the time of installation we can manage this section. First time launch we can show a window where the owner of the KIOSK can enter the merchant credit card details. But the issue is if he want to edit the details, how can we provide a way?  Since the application in KIOSK mode user cannot choose any other short cut keys.

If you have any idea please guide me.

Regards

Ranish

Comment: It sounds like all you need to do is allow the user to get back to the configuration screen... Couldn't you just add a button control or an event handler that listens for a certain key combination and navigates the user back to the configuration page? Use a popup to collect a password before processing the navigation if you need to protect the information.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I had already planned to  go with this way.  I didn't find  any another suitable solution.